# How to define path where generated output file is placed using jpackage (windows)

Tags: java, windows-installer, jpackage

Im trying to create an installer for my java app using jpackage.
This is what I have right now:
`jpackage --type msi --app-version "2.0" --input . --dest . --main-jar .\FitnessGUI.jar --main-class Main --win-shortcut --win-menu` 
This works fine, but I want to be able to choose where the program will be stored when installed.
What I have, according to [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html), defaults to the current working directory.
Im not sure what this means.
I have no idea where the app will be outputed on another person's computer.

I tried to use `--dest "C:\ "`, but i get:
`Destination directory C:\ is not writable`
Also tried `--dest "C:\Program Files"`, but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

--win-dir-chooser solves this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).